# New line character when using sklearn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, data-manipulation, countvectorizer

I have a list of strings like:

```
docs = ['this is a line\nthis is another line', 'this is another doc']
```

I would like [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to find all the char-n-gram in a given range, without excluding the `\n` character. That is to say that one token could be: `'a line\nthis'`. The default preprocessor seems to fail in doing this and `\n` are always treated like spaces. I tried to replace the preprocessor with an identity function and that did not work either.

Comment: you will need to change the default value for parameter `token_pattern=u'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`

Comment: @MaxU That I am aware, token_pattern is only ever used when analyzer == 'word'.

Comment: can you post a corresponding part of your code?